# Custom LINQ provider for Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: c#, linq, excel, oledb

Does anyone know a good custom LINQ provider to query data from Excel spreadsheets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Linq to Excel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) open source project implements a simple and intuitive LINQ provider for getting data from Excel spreadsheets. It takes care of creating the OLEDB connection and sql statement in the background as well as populating the return object properties.

For example, the code below reads the data from excel and returns a list of *User* objects. It automatically maps the column names in the spreadsheet to the property names on the class.

```
var book = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"C:\Users.xls");
var administrators = from x in book.Worksheet<User>()
                     where x.Role == "Administrator"
                     select x;
```

Checkout the [project home page](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) and be sure to view the [introductory video](http://www.vimeo.com/7689508).

Comment: It doesnt support other operators like UNION etc