# Why write a custom LINQ provider?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ienumerable

What is the benefit of writing a custom LINQ provider over writing a simple class which implements IEnumerable?

For example this [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767511/custom-linq-provider-for-excel-spreadsheets) shows Linq2Excel:

```
var book = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"C:\Users.xls");
var administrators = from x in book.Worksheet<User>()
                     where x.Role == "Administrator"
                     select x;
```

But what is the benefit over the "naive" implementation as IEnumerable?

Comment: Not sure why linq-to-excel profits from IQueryable, but there are are cases where it makes the code much faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Linq provider's purpose is to basically "translate" Linq expression trees (which are built behind the scenes of a query) into the native query language of the data source. In cases where the data is already in memory, you don't need a Linq provider; Linq 2 Objects is fine. However, if you're using Linq to talk to an external data store like a DBMS or a cloud, it's absolutely essential.

The basic premise of any querying structure is that the data source's engine should do as much of the work as possible, and return only the data that is needed by the client. This is because the data source is assumed to know best how to manage the data it stores, and because network transport of data is relatively expensive time-wise, and so should be minimized. Now, in reality, that second part is "return only the data asked for by the client"; the server can't read your program's mind and know what it really needs; it can only give what it's asked for. Here's where an intelligent Linq provider absolutely blows away a "naive" implementation. Using the IQueryable side of Linq, which generates expression trees, a Linq provider can translate the expression tree into, say, a SQL statement that the DBMS will use to return the records the client is asking for in the Linq statement. A naive implementation would require retrieving ALL the records using some broad SQL statement, in order to provide a list of in-memory objects to the client, and then all the work of filtering, grouping, sorting, etc is done by the client.

For example, let's say you were using Linq to get a record from a table in the DB by its primary key. A Linq provider could translate `dataSource.Query<MyObject>().Where(x=>x.Id == 1234).FirstOrDefault()` into "SELECT TOP 1 * from MyObjectTable WHERE Id = 1234". That returns zero or one records. A "naive" implementation would probably send the server the query "SELECT * FROM MyObjectTable", then use the IEnumerable side of Linq (which works on in-memory classes) to do the filtering. In a statement you expect to produce 0-1 results out of a table with 10 million records, which of these do you think would do the job faster (or even work at all, without running out of memory)?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to write a LINQ provider if you only want to use the LINQ-to-Objects (i.e. `foreach`-like) functionality for your purpose, which mostly works against in-memory lists.

You *do* need to write a LINQ provider if you want to analyse the expression tree of a query in order to translate it to something else, like SQL. The ExcelQueryFactory you mentioned seems to work with an OLEDB-Connection for example. This possibly means that it doesn't need to load the whole excel file into memory when querying its data.

Answer (score 3):

In general performance. If you have some kind of index you can do a query much faster than what is possible on a simple `IEnumerable<T>`.

Linq-To-Sql is a good example for that. Here you transform the linq statement into another for understood by the SQL server. So the server will do the filtering, ordering,... using the indexes and doesn't need to send the whole table to the client which then does it with linq-to-objects.

But there are simpler cases where it can be useful too:

If you have a tree index over the propery `Time` then a range query like `.Where(x=>(x.Time>=now)&&(x.Time<=tomorrow))` can be optimized a lot, and doesn't need to iterate over every item in the enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ will provide deferred execution as much as maximum possible to improve the performance.

IEnumurable<> and IQueryable<> will totally provide different program implementations. IQueryable will give native query by building expression tree dynamically which provides good performance indeed then IEnumurable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff963710.aspx

if we are not sure we may use [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword and dynamically it will initialize a most suitable type.